# Integral of product spherical harmonics

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, spherical-harmonics

I'm trying to calculate this  integral:

$$\int_0 ^\pi\int_0^{2\pi} [\sin\theta(\cos\theta \sin \phi + \sin\theta \cos(2\phi))]^2 \sin\theta  d\phi d\theta  $$

We could compute this integral directly. Or notice that it's a linear combination of product of several spherical harmonics and apply Wigner 3-j symbols.

But I've been told that this is integral is very easy to solve, so there must be an easier method.

Could someone give me an indication.

Comment: Expanding doesn't look that annoying, but another method would surely be interesting.

Comment: Well, the actual value of this integral is $\frac{4\pi}{3}, which is the volume of a unit sphere. Could this be hinting at a nice geometric interpretation of the integral?